# Show Alert dialog from state

Tags: flutter, dart, android-alertdialog

```
 void initState() {
super.initState();
showAlertDialog(context);
```

i want to show alertdialog in state

I've tried the following methods but it doesn't work

can you tell me what to do!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do by using 'addPostFrameCallback' method.

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/scheduler/SchedulerBinding/addPostFrameCallback.html

```
void initState() {
    super.initState();
    WidgetsBinding.instance
        .addPostFrameCallback((_) => showAlertDialog(context));
  }
```